# Obtener valor de elemento de array jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, array

Estoy intentando obtener los valores de los elementos de un `array` en `jQuery`.

Creo el `array` a partir de varios `<span></span>` que tengo en `HTML` de esta forma:

```
var elems = document.getElementsByTagName( "span" );
var arr = jQuery.makeArray( elems );
```

Pero luego, cuando voy a intentar obtener el valor de, por ejemplo, `arr[0]` con:

```
arr[0].val();
```

Me da error.

Un Saludo.

Comment: al hacer "var elems = document.getElementsByTagName( "span" );" elems ya es un array, pruebalo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La forma de acceder al texto contenido en un tag usando javascrtipt puro y jquery es distinto, en el primer caso es `.innertext`, es una propiedad del objeto, en jquery la forma de acceder es `text()`, una función.

Además, los retornos de los selectores tanto de javascrtipt puro como de jquery no son un array, son objetos, al menos el retorno de estos selectores. Pero lo puedes convertir en array usando lo que se llama [Asignación por destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/Destructuring_assignment), jquery tiene a su vez, un metodo propio para acceder a elementos usando indices: `eq(indice)`

```js
const spans = [...document.getElementsByTagName("span")];

//un elemento con vanilla js
console.log(spans[0].innerText);

//todos los elementos con vanilla js
spans.forEach(e => console.log(e.innerText));


//un elemento con jquery
$("span").eq(0).text();

//todos los elementos con jquery
$("span").each(function() {
  console.log($(this).text())
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<span>uno</span>

<span>dos</span>

<span>tres</span>

<span>cuatro</span>

<span>cinco</span> ​
```

El destructuring para selectores jquery sería `[...$("span")]`, igual que vanillajs, para seleccionar un elemento sin el destructuring también se puede hacer `$("span")["0"]`, en donde el indice es un string.

Comment: Gracias, me ha servido tu solución

Answer (score 1):

El error es que estas asumiendo que el arreglo `arr` contiene [objetos `jQuery`](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/jquery-object/).

### Solución:

[`jQuery.makeArray(elems)`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.makeArray/) devuelve un arreglo con la referencia a los `HTMLElement` del `DOM`.

Si quieres usar métodos de objetos `jQuery`, debes convertirlos.

#### Ejemplo usando de [`$(element)`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-element)

```js
var elems = document.getElementsByTagName( "span" );
var arr = jQuery.makeArray( elems );
// Convertimos arr[0] a un objeto jQuery
var $el = $(arr[0]);
console.log($el.text());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>Hola</span>
<span>mundo!</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Eso es porque `<span>` no tiene un atributo `value`. Tienes que usar `.html()` o `.text()` para obtener el valor dentro del `<span>`.

```
arr[0].html();
```

Comment: Me sigue dando este error: "Uncaught TypeError: arr[0].text is not a function"

Comment: Colocaste los paréntesis al llamar la función text() ?